# Remove All Attachments from document xpages

Tags: xpages, attachment

In my document i have multiple **"Body"** field which contains Rich-Text data as well as attachment files which is of type *(Data Type: MIME Part)*.
My purpose is to only delete the attachment files from my document. I tried this,

```
 if (document1.getAttachmentList("body").isEmpty()) {
    requestScope.alist = "No attachments in body";
} else {
    document1.removeAllAttachments("body");
    document1.save();
    requestScope.alist = "All attachments removed from body";
}
```

where **document1** is my data source name, by this code it works properly.

**But**, i want to retrieve document by

```
var doc:NotesDocument  = database.getDocumentByUNID(context.getUrlParameter("documentId"));
```

where it does not works.
    I had even tried by this code,

```
 var doc3:NotesDocument  = database.getDocumentByUNID(context.getUrlParameter("documentId"));
    var item:NotesItem =doc3.getFirstItem("$FILE");
    item.remove();
    doc3.save();
```

But, here problem is that it also deleting rich text data from document.

Is there any other solution can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first working code you have a the NotesXSPDocument, but in the second example you have the NotesDocument.
may be it is an idea to convert the NotesDocument to a NotesXSPDocument so you can use the first example
To convert it in SSJS this example may help you
https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=wrap-notesdocument-into-notesxspdocument

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between the "NotesXspDocument" and "NotesDocument" class in XPages

https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/xpages-notesxspdocument-vs-notesdocument.htm